# undefined reference to 'function' in Xilinx Eclipse SDK

Tags: c, sdk, undefined-reference

I am confronting

> undefined-reference to 'function'

in my C code using Xilinx Eclipse SDK. However,  the functions is already built ! 
In fact, I found a [[solved]](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/SDK-undefined-reference/m-p/818822/highlight/false#M43896) similar issue, but I couldn't reflect the solution to my case.

this my console output:

```
13:40:08 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project FH_TX_2 ****
make all 
'Building target: FH_TX_2.elf'
'Invoking: MicroBlaze gcc linker'
mb-gcc -L"D:\Users\dell\Vivado_projects\FHSS_Transmitter_2\FHSS_Transmitter_2.sdk\FH_TX_2_bsp\microblaze_0\libsrc" -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L"D:\Users\dell\Vivado_projects\FHSS_Transmitter_2\FHSS_Transmitter_2.sdk\FH_TX_2_bsp\microblaze_0\lib" -mlittle-endian -mcpu=v10.0 -mxl-soft-mul -Wl,--no-relax -Wl,--gc-sections -o "FH_TX_2.elf"  ./src/testperiph.o ./src/xiomodule_selftest_example.o   -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group
./src/testperiph.o: In function `main':
D:\Users\dell\Vivado_projects\FHSS_Transmitter_2\FHSS_Transmitter_2.sdk\FH_TX_2\Debug/../src/testperiph.c:71: undefined reference to `DA3_WriteSPI'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FH_TX_2.elf] Error 1

13:40:08 Build Finished (took 726ms)
```

makefile:

```
COMPILER=
ARCHIVER=
CP=cp
COMPILER_FLAGS=
EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=
LIB=libxil.a

RELEASEDIR=../../../lib
INCLUDEDIR=../../../include
INCLUDES=-I./. -I${INCLUDEDIR}

INCLUDEFILES=*.h
LIBSOURCES=*.c
OUTS = *.o

libs:
    echo "Compiling PmodDA3..."
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBSOURCES)
    $(ARCHIVER) -r ${RELEASEDIR}/${LIB} ${OUTS}
    make clean

include:
    ${CP} $(INCLUDEFILES) $(INCLUDEDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf ${OUTS}
```

---

```
    # Makefile generated by Xilinx.

PROCESSOR = microblaze_0
LIBRARIES = ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a
BSP_MAKEFILES := $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/libsrc/*/src/Makefile)
SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile, %, $(BSP_MAKEFILES))

ifneq (,$(findstring win,$(RDI_PLATFORM)))
 SHELL = CMD
endif

all: libs
    @echo 'Finished building libraries'

include: $(addsuffix /make.include,$(SUBDIRS))

libs: $(addsuffix /make.libs,$(SUBDIRS))

clean: $(addsuffix /make.clean,$(SUBDIRS))

$(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a: $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a
    cp -f $< $@

%/make.include: $(if $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a),$(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a,)
    @echo "Running Make include in $(subst /make.include,,$@)"
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.include,,$@) -s include  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=mb-gcc" "ARCHIVER=mb-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c -mcpu=v10.0 -mlittle-endian -mxl-soft-mul" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra"

%/make.libs: include
    @echo "Running Make libs in $(subst /make.libs,,$@)"
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.libs,,$@) -s libs  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=mb-gcc" "ARCHIVER=mb-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c -mcpu=v10.0 -mlittle-endian -mxl-soft-mul" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra"

%/make.clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.clean,,$@) -s clean 
clean:
    rm -f ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a
```

PmodDA3.h Libraray path

[image: X]

libxil.a

[image: X]

work window

[image: X]

PmodDA3.c

[image: X]

.o files are generated

[image: X]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188451/discussion-on-question-by-ahmed-muiead-undefined-reference-to-function-in-xili). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] the question.

Comment: -libxil.a was not there in the makefile before.. is it added now?

Comment: libxil.a was there by defualt. I didn't add it.